# Could not parse as expression: "@{email.getUrl()}" (template: "test" - line 10, col 8)

Tags: thymeleaf

I want to access url of other server from thymeleaf page. How to do this?
Have a look to my controller.

```
@GetMapping("/getJSPage")
    public String getJSP(Model theModel)
    {
        // String url = "https://test-node-api-test.herokuapp.com/";
        Email email = new Email();
        theModel.addAttribute("email", email);
        return "test";
    }
```

My Email class

```
class Email
{
    private String mail;

    public String getURL(){
        return "https://test-node-api-test.herokuapp.com/";
    }
}
```

and here is my test.HTML file

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Send HTML Email using JSP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Send Email using JSP</h1>
<p>
    <a th:href="@{email.getUrl()}"> clickable</a>
    <a th:href="@{https://test-node-api-test.herokuapp.com/}"> clickable</a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Below link `<a th:href="@{https://test-node-api-test.herokuapp.com/}"> clickable</a>` is hard-code, it's working but `<a th:href="@{email.getUrl()}"> clickable</a>` is generating error

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "@{email.getUrl()}" (template: "test" - line 10, col 8)
```

How Can i solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Standard URL Syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html#using-expressions-in-urls), if you want to use an expression when creating a url, you have to surround it with `${...}`.

```
<a th:href="@{${email.getURL()}}"> clickable</a>
```

Also, `getURL()` should match the getter exactly.  You have `getURL()` and `getUrl()` in your example code.